# Is there any dvb-t library for android?

Tags: android, dvb

I have an android STB and I'd like to know if there is any library with I can use the built in DVB-T tuner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which STB do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no DVB-T library for android.

However, you can develop your own:

Firstly, is your DVB-T device supported by the kernel?  To check, see if DVB related debug comes out of [dmesg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) when you boot up the box.  Also, [ls /dev/dvb*](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Device_nodes_and_character_devices) to see what is already there.

If there is no DVB support in the kernel, you will need to add it.  First you need access to the kernel source. Using this, modify the kernel [menuconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig) to add DVB related modules, and specific ones for your tuner - sometimes some Remote Control ones are required also.  Then build these modules, and insmod the modules on the box.  Sometimes [firmware is required](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers#If_the_Modules_did_not_load_correctly_or_the_device_is_still_not_configured_correctly_for_use:) too. Check the initial check again.

Then you can cross-compile [dvb-apps](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/LinuxTV_dvb-apps) for android (specifically [tzap](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Tzap)), or the newer [v4l-utils](http://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git) for android.  This gives you c code to tune to DVB-T transponders.  Then write some [JNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) to access the API from Java, and create an app to perform tuning.

Finally, you can send a URI to the [/dev/dvb0.dvr0](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Device_nodes_and_character_devices), to a third-party video player like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html). This is a TS stream containing MPEG-2 for SD, and H264 for HD.

As you can see, it is a lot of work, but entirely possible.

Comment: I'm sure that there is dvb support in the kernel, because there is an app on the device which can handle dvb-t, but I want to implement this functionality in my app.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if I can do that things with windows. Because windows doesn't have GNU make. Is there a way to somehow do something similar to make in windows? I saw MinGW but I can't make it work.